# Return cursor to starting position

Tags: android, cursor

I want to be able to scan a tag and then populate this data on the listview. I have managed to do this successfully.

However I do not want to keep tapping the editText in order to return the cursor back. The scanning is setup in emulator mode, so when you scan the tag the tag's info gets populated where ever the cursor is.

The problem I am having is once I scan the tag, the cursor does not return back to the editText automatically which means when I want to read another tag I have to keep presses the editText in order for the cursor to return to this place.

The listview gets the data from the editText. The code is shown below with pics of what I have now. From the pics you see that the cursor fails to go back to the editText automatically.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 EditText etRfidNo;
 TextView textView;
 private Set<String> epc = new HashSet<>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> contactAdapter;
 String single_epc;
 Button scan;
 ListView listView;
 boolean set = true;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    etRfidNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRfidNo);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewID);

    TextView textV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    etRfidNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            single_epc = String.valueOf(s);
            if(s.length() == 10)
            {
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                epc.add("\n" + etRfidNo.getText().toString() + ", " + DateFormat.getInstance().format(currentDate));
                display();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
 }

 public void display() {
    contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<>(epc));

    listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

  }

}
```

[Starting the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcD42.png)

[Data populated on listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6gL.png)

Xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.name.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.83" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etRfidNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="scan"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listviewID"
     android:layout_width="368dp"
     android:layout_height="282dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.276"
     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put focus on your editText View after scanning of each tag, so cursor will be shown without user input

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Code as follows -

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            single_epc = String.valueOf(s);
            if(s.length() == 10)
            {
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                epc.add("\n" + etRfidNo.getText().toString() + ", " + DateFormat.getInstance().format(currentDate));
                display();
                etRfidNo.requestFocus();      //Putting focus back
            }
        }
```

**Edit (Fix Issue with XML)**

There are issues with your xml file. `TextView` is getting overlapped by `EditText` which is further overlapped by `ListView` and there is no horizontal constraint set on your `ListView` as well. I will suggest you to go through [Constraint Layout Guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0) to get more info.

So in simple word, when you are attaching adapter to your `ListView`, it is getting focus atomically because then `ListView` become the first child of View Hierarchy in your xml. I have updated your layout to use simple linear layout, code as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRfidNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="scan"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above xml result as follows -

[image]

Happy Coding !

Comment: It is still not displaying the cursor on the editText

Comment: strange ... put etRfidNo.setText(""); just before calling requestFocus()

Comment: I did a little repro and for me EditText was not loosing focus untill I use back button to close soft keyboard, how your edit text is loosing focus at first place .. ?

Comment: It is losing focus as soon as I scan a tag and the data is displayed in the listview.

Comment: I found issue with your xml file, please check my edit on answer

Comment: I have solved it. Your solution was part of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: glad you fixed it yourself... please accept answer if it did help you. :)

Comment: What android studio are you using. Mine UI looks very old fashioned as compared to your one.

Comment: its actually emulator screen you see in screen shot,
`Emulator : Pixel 2 XL API 23` and `Android Studio: 3.5`